# DataContractSerialization works for one object, fails for a similar one

Tags: datacontractserializer, datacontract

I serialize successfully the following class

```
[DataContract]
public class Event
{           
    [DataMember] public virtual string EventId { get; set; }        
    [DataMember] public virtual string Name { get; set; }        
    [DataMember] public virtual string Editable { get; set; }        
    [DataMember] public virtual DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }            
    [DataMember] public virtual Function Function { get; set; }        
    [DataMember] public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual IList<EventParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual IList<EventParameterOption> Options { get; set; }

    public Event()
    {
        Parameters = new List<EventParameter>();
        Options = new List<EventParameterOption>();
    }
}
```

but the same code produces an exception when serializing the following

```
[DataContract]
public class Attribute
{
    [DataMember] public virtual string AttributeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual Function Function { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual string Editable { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual string Column { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual DateTime? LastExecution { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public virtual IList<AttributeParameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    public Attribute()
    {
        Parameters = new List<AttributeParameter>();
    }
}
```

and the exception points to the User property of the Attribute class.

**Type 'UserProxy' with data contract name 'UserProxy:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.**

The code I use for serializing is

```
public static byte[] SerializeObjectDataContract(object obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())            
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I really don't understand what differs between the two serializations. Removing the DataMember attribute from the User property allows the serialization to complete, however I do need to serialize the User too.

Comment: The solution is pretty much in the error message. Just read up on the KnownTypeAttribute: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but I do not use any inheritance, interface or object type properties

Comment: Do you mean in your Attribute class? No, but your User class probably is, and it needs to be serialized too.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see that you are successfully serializing your User class in the first example but not the second. That's a bit of a mystery, is that the exact same class in both cases, or is it just named the same?

Comment: yes same class. with the typical datacontract/datamember attributes.

Comment: Jesus, it was NHibernate lazyloading the User object on the Attribute mapping class. I hate NHibernate.